# Geth node logs Killed after uploading smart contract

Tags: go-ethereum, geth

I'm experiencing an issue with geth.

After I upload a smart contract through RPC, the node logs `Killed` and dies.

Does anyone have an idea what the issue could be? Or how I could debug it?

```
geth
    --networkid=$NETWORK_ID
    --bootnodes=enode://$(BOOTNODE_ID)@$(BOOTNODE_SERVICE_HOST):30301
    --rpc
    --rpcaddr=0.0.0.0
    --rpccorsdomain=\"*\"
    --datadir=/ethereum
    --debug
    --verbosity=4
    --identity=$HOSTNAME
    --gasprice '1'
    --syncmode 'full'
    --rpcport 8545
    --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner'
    --unlock $ACCOUNT
    --password /password.txt
    --mine
```